# Entity Framework Core error : insert or update on table "TblScheme" violates foreign key constraint "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error every time I try to update my database migration:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (23ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER TABLE "TblScheme" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId" FOREIGN KEY ("CompanyId") REFERENCES "TblCompanies" ("paramID") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Failed executing DbCommand (23ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE "TblScheme" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId" FOREIGN KEY ("CompanyId") REFERENCES "TblCompanies" ("paramID") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "TblScheme" violates foreign key constraint "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId"

DETAIL: Key (CompanyId)=(0) is not present in table "TblCompanies".
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|215_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
  Exception data:
    Severity: ERROR
    SqlState: 23503
    MessageText: insert or update on table "TblScheme" violates foreign key constraint "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId"
    Detail: Key (CompanyId)=(0) is not present in table "TblCompanies".
    SchemaName: public
    TableName: TblScheme
    ConstraintName: FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId
    File: ri_triggers.c
    Line: 2539
    Routine: ri_ReportViolation
23503: insert or update on table "TblScheme" violates foreign key constraint "FK_TblScheme_TblCompanies_CompanyId"

DETAIL: Key (CompanyId)=(0) is not present in table "TblCompanies".
```

This happens when I try to make a new relationship in an existing table, I had to drop and recreate the table as a workaround but it is not efficient. Is there any step I am missing when doing this?

Comment: There is probably data in those tables that directly conflict with the foreign key you are trying to implement.

Comment: CompanyId in your TblScheme Table is required so its set to be 0, while there's no CompanyId=0 is your CompanyId.
Solution is set CompanyId to be nullable and after creation the table and updating the data make it required

Comment: @Lajil Adel Thank you very much it's working now. This is because I already have rows filled into the table, So when I create a relationship it tries to refer to the new related table when created. By default, it tries to assign the column CompanyId as 0. Unfortunately, TblCompany doesn't have a PK with the value 0.